# create an array and sort it in ascending and descending way [MIPS]

Tags: arrays, sorting, mips

I have to ask the user a number, store that number and then create a vector of that size and ask the user for numbers to store in the array, so far I have this, but I don't know how to continue:

```
.data
 string1: .asciiz "\nIntroduce size of array\n"
 string2: .asciiz "\nIntroduce next number\n"
 string3: .asciiz "\nBye\n"

 array: .word

.text
main:   
 la $t4, array       #store the direction of the array

 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, string1
 syscall
 li $v0, 5
 syscall
 move $t0, $v0      #t0 = vector size

 asknum:
 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, string2
 syscall
 li $v0, 5
 syscall
 move $t5, $v0      #t5 = num introduced
 sw $t5, 4($t4)     #save number in the array, the program crashes here
 add $t2, $t2, 1
 bne $t2, $t0, asknum

 la $a0, cadena3
 li $v0,4
 syscall
 li $v0,10
 syscall
```

I don't know why the program crashes when I try to store the number (I guess I'm storing it wrong) and I honestly have no idea how to sort an array in MIPS lenguage, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You've only reserved space for a single word (i.e. 4 bytes) at `array`, and then you attempt to write to `array+4` (through `4($t4)`). Don't write to memory that you haven't allocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple fix is to change:

```
array: .word
```

Into:

```
    .align 4
array: .space 1000
```

(i.e.) This will allow `1000 / 4` numbers or `250`.

Another bug: You were never filling the first element of `array`. You were filling `array[1]` and *all* values were being stored there. So, change:

```
sw $t5,4($t4)
```

Into:

```
sw $t5,0($t4)
addiu $t4,$t4,4
```

Another [minor] bug is that you're relying on `$t2` to have a zero value without explicitly setting it. So, add this just before `asknum:`

```
li $t2,0
```

---

Here's the cleaned up code. I added a limit check on the user's count [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
    .data
string1:    .asciiz     "Introduce size of array: "
string2:    .asciiz     "Introduce next number: "
string3:    .asciiz     "\nBye\n"

    .align  4
array:      .space      1000

    .text

main:
    # prompt user for array size
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,string1
    syscall

    li      $v0,5
    syscall
    move    $t0,$v0                 # remember user's count

    li      $t1,250                 # get max size -- user's answer too large?
    bgt     $t0,$t1,main            # yes, ask again

    la      $t4,array               # get the address of the array
    li      $t2,0                   # set index

asknum:
    # prompt user for number
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,string2
    syscall

    # get the array value and store it
    li      $v0,5
    syscall
    sw      $v0,0($t4)              # save number in the array

    addi    $t4,$t4,4               # advance array pointer
    addi    $t2,$t2,1               # advance array index
    bne     $t2,$t0,asknum          # more to do? if yes, loop

    la      $a0,string3
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    li      $v0,10
    syscall
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Can you explain to me how to access the numbers of the array? I'm trying to print them using this, but it's printing 0 all the time:

```
    li      $s0,0xFFFF0010
    li      $s1,0xFFFF0011
    lw      $t8,4($t4)              # get the first element of the array
    div     $t3,$t8,10
```

For a simple printing of the array, I'm not sure how this code helps you. Without the context of the surrounding code, it's difficult for me to speculate as to what the code is doing.

It looks like you're trying to do your own equivalent of `printf("%d",num)`, but there is already a syscall to output an integer to the screen. I'd use that. But ... If you truly need to "roll your own", I've included code to do that.

Printing the array is similar to the input of the array.

I've reworked the previous example code. The input of the array is now a function. I removed the hardwired limit value of 250 in favor of using a new label: `arrend` [so, have a look]

Once it was a function, it was a simple matter to copy, paste, and rework it into a new function `arrprt` that prints the array.

To manually do what syscall 1 does, I've added the `prtint` function. `arrprt` will use the syscall, but if you want it to use `prtint`, comment out the syscall and uncomment the block that calls `prtint`

Here's the new code:

```
    .data
msg_siz:    .asciiz     "Introduce size of array: "
msg_num:    .asciiz     "Introduce next number: "
msg_nl:     .asciiz     "\n"
msg_bye:    .asciiz     "\nBye\n"

    .align  4
array:      .space      1000
arrend:

prtint_hex: .asciiz     "0123456789ABCDEF"
prtint_buf: .space      100
    .text

main:
    jal     asknum                  # read in array
    jal     arrprt                  # print array

    # say goodbye
    la      $a0,msg_bye
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    # exit program
    li      $v0,10
    syscall

# asknum -- read in array of numbers
#
# RETURNS:
#   s0 -- array count
#
# registers:
#   t1 -- maximum array count
#   t2 -- current array index
#   t4 -- array pointer
asknum:
    # prompt user for array size
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,msg_siz
    syscall

    # read in user's count
    li      $v0,5
    syscall
    move    $s0,$v0                 # remember user's count

    la      $t4,array               # get address of array

    # get number words of array
    la      $t1,arrend              # get address of array end
    sub     $t1,$t1,$t4             # get array byte length
    srl     $t1,$t1,2               # get array word count

    blez    $s0,asknum              # user's count too small? yes, ask again
    bgt     $s0,$t1,asknum          # user's count too large? yes, ask again

    li      $t2,0                   # set index

    # prompt user for number
asknum_loop:
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,msg_num
    syscall

    # get the array value and store it
    li      $v0,5
    syscall
    sw      $v0,0($t4)              # save number in the array

    addi    $t4,$t4,4               # advance array pointer
    addi    $t2,$t2,1               # advance array index
    bne     $t2,$s0,asknum_loop     # more to do? if yes, loop

    jr      $ra                     # return

# arrprt -- print array of numbers
#
# arguments:
#   s0 -- array count
#
# registers:
#   t6 -- current array index
#   t7 -- array pointer
arrprt:
    subiu   $sp,$sp,4
    sw      $ra,0($sp)

    la      $t7,array               # get address of array
    li      $t6,0                   # set index

arrprt_loop:
    # print array value (using syscall)
    lw      $a0,0($t7)              # get array value
    li      $v0,1
    syscall

    # print array value (using prtint)
    ###lw       $a0,0($t7)              # get array value
    ###li       $a1,10                  # get number base to use
    ###jal      prtint

    # output a newline
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,msg_nl
    syscall

    addi    $t7,$t7,4               # advance array pointer
    addi    $t6,$t6,1               # advance array index
    bne     $t6,$s0,arrprt_loop     # more to do? if yes, loop

    lw      $ra,0($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,4
    jr      $ra                     # return

# prtint -- print single integer
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- integer to print
#   a1 -- integer base to use (e.g. 10)
#
# registers:
#   t2 -- current array index
#   t3 -- ascii digits pointer
#   t4 -- buffer pointer
prtint:
    la      $t4,prtint_buf          # get address of scratch buffer
    la      $t3,prtint_hex          # get ascii digits pointer

prtint_loop:
    div     $a0,$a1                 # number / base
    mflo    $a0                     # get next number value
    mfhi    $t1                     # get remainder

    addu    $t1,$t3,$t1             # get address of ascii digit
    lb      $t1,0($t1)              # get ascii digit

    sb      $t1,0($t4)              # store it in buffer
    addiu   $t4,$t4,1               # advance buffer pointer

    bnez    $a0,prtint_loop         # more to do? yes, loop

    sb      $zero,0($t4)            # store EOS

    # NOTE: the buffer we just created is _reversed_ (e.g. for a value of
    # 123, it will be "321"), so we need to reverse it to be useful

    subiu   $t4,$t4,1               # back up to last ascii digit
    la      $t3,prtint_buf          # point to buffer start

prtint_revloop:
    bge     $t3,$t4,prtint_revdone  # are we done? yes, fly

    lb      $t0,0($t3)              # get lhs char
    lb      $t1,0($t4)              # get rhs char

    sb      $t0,0($t4)              # store lhs char
    sb      $t1,0($t3)              # store rhs char

    addiu   $t3,$t3,1               # advance lhs pointer (forward)
    subiu   $t4,$t4,1               # advance rhs pointer (backward)
    j       prtint_revloop

prtint_revdone:
    # get the ascii string value and print it
    la      $a0,prtint_buf
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    jr      $ra                     # return
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has been really helpful

Comment: Can you explain me how to acces the numbers of the array? I'm trying to print them using this, but it's printing 0 all the time:

 li $s0, 0xFFFF0010 
 li $s1, 0xFFFF0011 
 
 lw $t8, 4($t4)   # get the first element of the array
 div $t3,$t8,10

Answer (score 0):

first thing when you store number then add t4 with 4 for next number u didnot increment index u overwrite the index.

second thing 
try this

li $t7,0
array($t7)

just like c,c++ style